# Manipulate Array of pointer to 2D int Array

Tags: c

I have this code :

```
int (*pieces) [10][10];
```

I want to dynamically allocate it into a function.

```
createPieces(int* (**pieces)){

*pieces = malloc(sizeof(int[10][10])*12); //12 = for example but it's a variable

}
```

And I try to initialize it like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
                (pieces+i)[x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

unfortunately that doesn't work. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: An `int[][]` can  ***NOT*** be interpreted as an `int **`.

Comment: So how can I handle it ?

Comment: In your last question when you had a pointer to 2D array and passed the address so you could allocated storage for the pointer-to-pointer-to 2D array made sense. It seems you have gotten lost between then and now. If you have `int (*pieces) [10][10];` and pass the address to your `createPieces()` function would be `createPieces(int (**pieces)[10][10]){` where `int (**pieces)[10][10]` is a pointer-to-pointer-to `int[10][10]`. You can then allocate with `*pieces = malloc (sizeof **pieces * 12)` to allocate storage for 12 10x10 arrays accessible through `pieces` back in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
int (*pieces) [10][10];
```

This is declaring a 10x10 array of pointers to integer

suggest:

in the caller:

```
...
int (*array[12])[10][10] = NULL;
array = createArray( 12 );
...

int * createArray( size_t instances )
{
    // get a pointer for 12 instances, each pointer initialized to NULL
    int *pieces = calloc( sizeof (int *), instances ); 
    // check for malloc failure here

    for( size_t i=0; i < instances; i++ )
    {
        // fill in a pointer to point to an array (10x10) of integers
        pieces[i] = malloc( sizeof( int ) *100 );
        // check for malloc failure here
    }

    // add code to initialize each 10x10 array instance here.
```

The above will result in an array of 12 pointers to integer.  Where each of those pointers will point to a 10x10 array of integers.

Note: used `calloc()` so if there is a memory allocation failure, makes it easy to 'clean up'.

```
    return pieces;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% clear on your intent, but I think I understand you want to start with your *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int[10][10]` array, pass the address to a function to allocate and then initialize the values for the storage of all twelve of the 10x10 blocks allocated. If that isn't correct, drop a comment below.

As mentioned in my comment to an earlier of your questions, any time you receive an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, it is likely due to abusing a pointer and attempting to access a memory address that isn't a valid memory address for your program (like attempting to access an address way down in the *system-reserved* memory range). This usually occurs when you use a stored value as an address due to improperly dereferencing one-to-many times, etc..

Presuming that `int (*pieces) [10][10];` isn't a global variable (which is should not be to begin with), you can declare your array and then pass to `createpieces()` for allocation as follows:

```
int main (void) {
    
    int (*pieces) [10][10];
    size_t n = 12;
    
    createpieces (&pieces, n);
    
    if (!pieces)        /* validate EVERY allocation, before using the block */
        return 1;
```

While I would recommend having `createpieces()` return a pointer to `int (*)[10][10]` so you need only pass the number of 10x10 arrays to allocate and assign the return to your pointer -- there isn't anything wrong with passing the address and allocating (which is the only way possible when the function is a callback, etc..)

Your `createpieces()` function could be written as:

```
void createpieces (int (**pieces)[10][10], size_t narrays)
{
    *pieces = malloc (sizeof **pieces * narrays);
    
    if (!*pieces)   /* validate the allocation */
        perror ("malloc-*pieces");
}
```

Now after your allocation, since it was a single-allocation, you have a contiguous block of memory, so if you want to initialize all values to `1`, simply include `string.h` and then following your call to `createpieces()`:

```
memset (pieces, 1, sizeof *pieces * n);
```

Much easier than nested loops (and more efficient), but by way of example, you can use nested loops if you like. The following initializes the elements of each 10x19 array to `1...100`:

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                pieces[i][j][k] = j * 10 + k + 1;
```

(**note:** the type consistency in the loop variables)

Adding a short `prnpieces()` function to output all twelve arrays, you could do:

```
void prnpieces (int (*pieces)[10][10], size_t narrays)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < narrays; i++) {
        printf ("\narray: %2zu\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                printf (" %3d", pieces[i][j][k]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void createpieces (int (**pieces)[10][10], size_t narrays)
{
    *pieces = malloc (sizeof **pieces * narrays);
    
    if (!*pieces)   /* validate the allocation */
        perror ("malloc-*pieces");
}

void prnpieces (int (*pieces)[10][10], size_t narrays)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < narrays; i++) {
        printf ("\narray: %2zu\n", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                printf (" %3d", pieces[i][j][k]);
            putchar ('\n');
        }
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    int (*pieces) [10][10];
    size_t n = 12;
    
    createpieces (&pieces, n);
    
    if (!pieces)        /* validate EVERY allocation, before using the block */
        return 1;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                pieces[i][j][k] = j * 10 + k + 1;
    
    prnpieces (pieces, n);
    free (pieces);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr22d

array:  0
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

<snip>

array: 11
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ptr22d
==12640== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12640== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12640== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12640== Command: ./bin/ptr22d
==12640==

array:  0
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50
  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70
  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

<snip>
==12640==
==12640== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12640==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12640==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 5,824 bytes allocated
==12640==
==12640== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12640==
==12640== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12640== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.